# Tariff impact measurement

Tags: tariffs

As I understand it, tariffs are used to generate revenue for governments and also punish suppliers or influence their respective governments.  Usually the end user pays the tariff.

Is there a metric that is used to measure which stakeholder is impacted?

Comment: Maybe try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_incidence